# How do I make the div inside the container use just 6 of the 12 columns in bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-system

The code correctly shows two columns on large screens. But for tablet sized screens, both divs take up their own row, each using 12 columns.

I want each of them to be in the same container using 6 columns. I have tried changing the numbers in the classes `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4` 
but nothing has worked.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-2">
        <p><b>We Offer:</b></p>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <ul>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 ">
            <ul>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can use container-fluid which should help with smaller screens, also you can try offsetting the column

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class = "row col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-2">
        <p><b>We Offer:</b></p>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <ul>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>

        </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 ">

        <ul>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/render/133129

Answer (score 1):

In addition to KyleMit's answer above, note that due to the "mobile-first" nature of bootstrap 3, you only need the "col-xs-6 col-lg-4" classes, the xs definition will apply to larger sizes unless overridden.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working as I'd expect it to. [**According to the Documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options), a small screen is anything less than **`768px`** which can actually be quite large. By opening the developer tools, you can see the screen dimensions whenever you resize a web page. You can use this to see how it deals with different breakpoints.

#### Here's a live demo of your code:

### [jsFiddle with Original Code](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/dpW85)

#### Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

#### Solution:

If you would like it to still have two columns at anything below 768 pixels, then change `col-xs-12` to `col-xs-6`, like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-2">
        <p><b>We Offer:</b></p>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <ul>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 ">
            <ul>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### [Working Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/dpW85/4/)

Answer (score 0):

On large screens you want two columns but on small screen you want a single column that only takes up 50% of the width?

You don't put column classes on `.row`. Ever.

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/vuyisu/1/**

Here `.col-md-X` is your "large" if by large you mean 1200px and up, change the `.col-md-X` to `.col-lg-X` and by tablet you mean just 768px - 992px you would change `.col-xs-X` to `.col-sm-X`. When you nest columns you need a surrounding `.row`.

```
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-6">
          <p><b>We Offer:</b></p>
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                   <li>test</li>
                   <li>test</li>
                   <li>test</li>
                   <li>test</li>
                </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                   <li>test</li>
                   <li>test</li>
                   <li>test</li>
                   <li>test</li>
                </ul>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```